# How to run VBA code for particular worksheet(Only in sheet1) (Irrespective of the active sheet)?

Tags: excel, vba

I am a newbie for a VBA coding.I am building custom Stock screener. For that I want to print a stock prices at particular times to different cells for my strategy.I developed a code somehow.But I don't know how to make it work in a particular sheet(sheet 1) irrespective of active sheets.
Following is the code which i pasted in a thisworkbook module.

Thanks in advance

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call ScheduleTask
End Sub


Public Sub ScheduleTask()
Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:46:00"), "ThisWorkbook.Execute"

End Sub

Public Sub Execute()
Debug.Print "Executing task", Now
Range("D8:D57").Copy
Range("T8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Call ScheduleTask1

End Sub

Public Sub ScheduleTask1()

Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:47:00"),"ThisWorkbook.Execute1"

End Sub

Public Sub Execute1()

Debug.Print "Executing task", Now
Range("D8:D57").Copy
Range("U8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Call ScheduleTask2

End Sub

Public Sub ScheduleTask2()

Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:47:00"), "ThisWorkbook.Execute2"

End Sub

Public Sub Execute2()

Debug.Print "Executing task", Now
Range("D8:D57").Copy
Range("V8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Call ScheduleTask
End Sub`enter code here`
```

Comment: For every Range statement you have, add the specified sheet before it like so: `Sheets(1).range` or better yet `Sheets("sheet name here").Range`

Answer (score 2):

Specify a worksheet for every `Range` object. If you don't do that then VBA will use the `ActiveSheet`.

For example

```
Range("D8:D57").Copy
```

will copy from the `ActiveSheet` but

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D8:D57").Copy
```

will copy from `Sheet1` of the worbkook this code is in (represented by `ThisWorkbook`).

Comment: I changed the code like below but it not not copying at all 


    Public Sub ScheduleTask2()

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:18:00"), "ThisWorkbook.Execute2"
    End Sub
    Public Sub Execute2()
    Debug.Print "Executing task", Now

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D8:D57").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("V8").PasteSpecial 
    Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, 
    Transpose:=False
    
    Call ScheduleTask
    End Sub

Comment: Any errors? This must work! Start the `Execute2` procedure directly to test if it works. Or go throug it step by step using F8.

Answer (score 1):

Also You can work with

```
dim wb as Workbook
dim SheetOne as Worksheet
dim RangeOne as Range

set wb = ThisWorkbook
set SheetOne = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
set RangeOne = SheetOne.Range("D8:D57")

RangeOne.Copy SheetOne.Range("T8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the worksheet to be used for every `Range` statement like so:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call ScheduleTask
End Sub


Public Sub ScheduleTask()
Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:46:00"), "ThisWorkbook.Dostuff"

End Sub

Public Sub Dostuff()
Dim Mysheet As Worksheet
Set Mysheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter sheet name here")
Debug.Print "Executing task", Now
Mysheet.Range("D8:D57").Copy
Mysheet.Range("T8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Call ScheduleTask1

End Sub

Public Sub ScheduleTask1()

Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:47:00"), "ThisWorkbook.Dostuff1"

End Sub

Public Sub Dostuff1()
Dim Mysheet As Worksheet
Set Mysheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter sheet name here")
Debug.Print "Executing task", Now
Mysheet.Range("D8:D57").Copy
Mysheet.Range("U8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Call ScheduleTask2

End Sub

Public Sub ScheduleTask2()

Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:47:00"), "ThisWorkbook.Dostuff2"

End Sub

Public Sub Dostuff2()
Dim Mysheet As Worksheet
Set Mysheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter sheet name here")
Debug.Print "Executing task", Now
Mysheet.Range("D8:D57").Copy
Mysheet.Range("V8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Call ScheduleTask
End Sub
```

Also do not use Execute as a sub name as it is also a command and will cause clashes.

Edited with @Pᴇʜ 's suggestions (twice)

Comment: I tried this code and it gives me syntax error on line 
Public Sub Execute()

Comment: Note that `Sheets(1)` and `Sheets("Sheet1")` can be 2 completely different sheets. Also `Sheets` and `Worksheets` is not the same.

Comment: What is the difference?can you elaborate if possible?

Comment: @Jones `Excecute` is a reserved word and must not be used as a procedure name. The difference is `Sheet(1)` is the first sheet in the tab list while `Sheets("Sheet1")` is the sheet whos tab is named `Sheet1` (which can be on position 5). `Sheets` contains all worksheets and chart sheets while `Worksheets` only contains worksheets. So If we want to run the code on a worksheet with a specific name we must use `Worksheets("SheetName")`. Or for the worksheet with position 1 `Worksheets(1)` if we use `Sheet(1)` it might be a chart sheet and `.Range` fails on charts.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ agreed, while this code works for most cases, if there is charts involved it will fail. I'll update my answer with your suggestions.

Comment: @Plutian Sorry to bother you again, but there is also a huge difference between `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook`. While `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that has focus / is on top while the code runs, `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook the code is written in. `ActiveWorkbook` can be changed by any user just clicking on a workbook. So it is much more reliable to use `ThisWorkbook` there are only rare cases when `ActiveWorkbook` is needed (eg. Add-Ins).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I thought the answer was easy basic knowledge, but then the master comes along... I'll change it again, and thank you for teaching me some useful lessons!

Comment: @Plutian Sorry :) The problem is that many people use VBA for *"quick and dirty"* things, and then they don't care about all these details. But if you are really interested in writing solid, reliable code you need to know the differences. I've read so many questions about *"My code works but sometimes it fails"* and then it is full of `ActiveSheet`, or `ActiveWorkbook` or `.Select`. So sometimes I may sound a bit pedantic. It might matter or not (depends on what the goal of the code is).

Comment: No need to apologize, I am an active advocate against using `.select` at any time for this exact reason. But I didn't realize this difference until you pointed it out, and it makes absolute sense. I am definitely interested in learning, which is the biggest reason I hang out here in the first place.